# Page source not showing advertisments for selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This should be a very straight forward element find which is just not occurring, I've add in a very long implicit wait to allow the page to load completely

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.smh.com.au")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("img_ad")
```

As well as wait loads based on element location

```
timeout = 10    
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '"img_ad'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
```

However, this element is not appearing despite me seeing it clearly in inspect mode in firefox

```
<img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/9181016285467049325" alt="" class="img_ad" width="970" height="250" border="0">
```

This is an advertisement on the page so I think there might be some funky code sitting on top of it which doesn't show in the driver, any advice on how to collect this?

Comment: Are you launching Firefox without ad blocker? Do you see the ad in the, launched by the Selenium, browser? If you're running your code on some remote machine, is it possible that some proxy cuts out the ads?

Answer (score 2):

The advert is in an iFrame so you need to switch this frame first.

But I found that after several page loads the adverts stopped appearing on the web-page. I did find that the adverts loaded nearly every time using `driver = webdriver.Opera()` but not in Chrome of Firefox, even using private browsing and clearing all browsing data.

If they appeared then this code worked.

To find the element by a partial class name I at first used `find_element_by_css_selector("amp-img[class^='img_ad']")`. Sometimes the element with the `img_ad` class is not present so you can use `driver.find_element_by_id("aw0")` which finds the data more often. Sometimes the web-page HTML does not even have this id so my code prints the HTML.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.smh.com.au")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

iFrame = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[1]
driver.switch_to.frame(iFrame)

try:
    # element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("amp-img[class^='img_ad']")
    # print(element.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("aw0")
    print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Advert not found")
    print(driver.page_source)

driver.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
<amp-img alt="" class="img_ad i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout" height="250" i-amphtml-layout="fixed" i-amphtml-ssr="" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/16664324514375864185" style="width:970px;height:250px;" width="970"><img alt="" class="i-amphtml-fill-content i-amphtml-replaced-content" decoding="async" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/16664324514375864185"></amp-img>
```

or:

```
<img src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/10498242030813793376" border="0" width="970" height="250" alt="" class="img_ad">
```

or:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```